Can holding down a mouse button be automated?
I would love to be able to scroll down a very long webpage without having to be near the computer.
The webpage has several thousand entries and they only keep loading and displaying as I get near the bottom of the list.
Putting a heavy object on the space bar doesn't work because it's a JS frame inside a webpage.
The webpage is the list of people I follow on Instagram, which is reaching the limit of 7500 and I need to get to the end to quickly unfollow and monitor, as I am sure I never manually followed that many people myself.
A glitch is making the number of accounts I follow stay the same even if I unfollow accounts (a very widespread issue).
I use a Logitech Trackman mouse on one the 2014 iMac and one of the side buttons is configured to scroll down. However I do not not how to "lock" this button in "pressed" positon (duct tape didn't work).
Another computer I have is a MacBook Pro 2019.
(Another device I would be open to do this on is an iPhone 13 Pro).
I am not finding any ways to do this simply, could this be done with Automator? I opened Automator and looked for scrolling and mouse related functions but couldn’t find anything. I am wondering if I can just record pressing the button down and have the computer repeat it indefinitely or if there is another way to do this.
I am open to system defaults, Terminal or Automator scripts, or free third-party options.

I don't have a total answer, but get Xcode to  use the Accessibility Inspector on Safari and enable UI scripting. Also, reach out to inquire who the web page's Section 508 ombudsperson is to ask about their web site. They might have an option to ease your loading issue like implementing command + down if you ask.

We have many, many posts if key command automation or emulating a wheel would work with your unknown web page.

@bmike not so unknown anymore as I detailed the reason behind my need in an edit of the question, hoping it will shed light on my process and frustration. A lot of the posts you linked to do not have a solution I can apply and/or reproduce because they are either obsolete or require high skillsets. The macbook doesn't have F1, F2 etc keys but the iMac does...

Keyboard Maestro would work (but is not free), as would custom JS directly in the browser. Did you check for any browser extension (Chrome or Firefox), or Greasemonkey scripts?

I've had good luck using a toothpick...

There is a post here (or on Ask Different) that demonstrates using applescript to scroll to the bottom of a long mail message by emulating a mouse click on the scroll bar until the bottom is reached. Perhaps that might be implementable in Safari.

@Mockman do you have a link for it? I looked for a bit but I'm not an expert at applescript. If you adapt it you could have an answer

This is the answer: Check whether scroll is finished using AppleScript. If you scroll up to the question, you should see a comment there about safari.

And something else to take a look at that works with Chrome and uses javascript.

@Mockman I looked at it, but I can't really make any sense of it. If you have a step by step in the very precise situation that I am describing, and you are able to successfully test it on your end, please do share

@bmike if you can make the answers you suggest fit the situation and make them accessible for entry-level automator users, I will be glad to accept it. But one of the links in your comment is dead (one of the answers to the second link) - thanks

I used a piece of freeware called MouseTools to automate clicking. It's no longer available from the original company (or their web domain now belongs to some other company), but there are GitHub repositories with the same name which might be essentially the same piece of software.
The version I had was controlled via bash/zsh (i.e. Terminal) commands, which I ran via AppleScript. Here's an outline of how the script could operate:
First generate an AppleScript prompt, something like "After clicking OK, quickly move the mouse where you want to click". Then add a short delay, for instance delay 2, which pauses the script for 2 seconds. Then you'll have time to move the mouse into the correct position for scrolling.
To use MouseTools get the location of your mouse pointer on screen:
set {x, y} to paragraphs of (do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -location")

Lastly, you need MouseTools to perform the clicks. The function below simulates a click at a particular location on screen, given by x and y. The theSwitches parameter was used to simulate holding down modifier keys such as Shift and Command, but you can remove it if not needed. Enclose this inside a loop construct to click repeatedly.
on click(mouseToolsPath, x, y, theSwitches)
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text) & theSwitches
end click


Unfortunately, the "page down" key does not work in this precise situation, as far as i know. I believe you should be able to test your solution if you have an Instagram account

I don't have an Instagram account. I'm unsure if the MouseTools binary can simulate mouse holds, but it can certainly simulate individual clicks, which you can then enclose in a loop construct to repeat them. It's also possible to it to capture the location of your mouse and pass those x-y paramaters into the click() function call in your loop. I'll add a sample code line into the answer for doing that.

I am bewildered at the thought that your suggestion is the simplest way to do this as this seems way out of my area of expertise

It might not be the simplest way. If you aren't comfortable with coding might be best to try and find another solution, hopefully somebody will chime in during the bounty period.

@MicroMachine Although, the answer as it now has almost all the necessary code, except the line to generate the prompt and the loop construct. Assuming you can get a copy of MouseTools, it might be easier than you think to find out how to code the rest of the script.
